# Correct approach for rendering optional param in blade

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I noticed that below construction is not correct for Blade

```
<div class="constant @if($some_condition)optional@endif">
```

cause this is converted to in PHP which is invalide

```
<div class="constant <?php if($some_condition): ?>optional<?php endif; ?>">
```

To make this statement work I need to put close tag on different line but it looks very bad, especially if there are many others attribute.

```
<div class="constant @if($some_condition)optional
@endif" data-id="1" tabindex="2" data-etc="...">
```

What is the right way of rendering such kind of conditions in Blade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the short version of `if` statement.

```
$some_condition ? 'optional' : ''
```

Using the code above, if the condition is true it will return the the string `'optional'`, if the condition is not true it will return an empty string I mean this `''`. Note, an empty string as attribute do nothing inside `Html` element.

In your case it should look like this:

```
<div class="constant {{ $some_condition ? 'optional' : '' }}">
```

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I use this approach. In this case it looks much better. I just wanna know what do experienced Laravels' developers in situations like this.

Comment: @PavloZhukov I am working with Laravel for 4 years. I do this when I have to use `if` statement inside `Html` tag. May be all others do the same. If anybody has more simplified solution, they might be answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use your suggestion.